# Kendo-Angular :How to represent list view of JSON object

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a JSON object , whose data needs to be represented in a list view

```
{
    "TestId": 2,
    "CurrentTestVersion": 1,
    "TestNumber": "2015-29059",
    "SharingData": 1.000000,
    "ThresholdValue": 0.0,
    "ExpireDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
    "UpdateDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00",
    "TestCurrency": "INR",
    "TestCode": "44300",
    "TestUCode": "UU",
    "IndexType": "TRE",
    "IndexUCode": "EUR",
    "IndexUMCode": "not",

}
```

Above data needs to be represented in a list format as below

[image]

I have tried with using row and column tags with span class

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="fs12px">Currency:
      {{test.TestCurrency}} </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="fs12px">CurrentTestVersion:
      {{test.CurrentTestVersion}} </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="fs12px">Expire Date :
      {{test.ExpireDate}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I achieve list view using Kendo, I have checked kendo list view documentation , but couldn't find to suit as it is also a grid.

Comment: It seems that you won't achieve that with KendoGrid (although I don't know kendo well, just quickly checked docs), and KendoList will do the trick. Here is a fork of the list example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ymo62?file=app%2Fproduct-list-item.component.ts . What you need to, is to provide a data row for each of the properties

Comment: @akkonard thanks for the suggestion but the json structure doesn’t suit as mentioned in the example as it iterates over same key name(ex. type of drink) which is not in my case.

Comment: you can iterate over object keys and values, this is super-easy, you could create another component and nest it in the list itself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yck55u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @akkonrad Thanks a lot , I'm able to iterate over object, how can I get the grid format like rows and columns using CSS

Comment: @akkonrad I have tried the border with 'outline' 
                    <table>
                        <tr *ngFor="let key of keys" style="outline: thin solid  #f7f7f7">
                            <td>
                                {{ key }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="outline: thin solid  #dee2e6">
                                {{ listData[key] }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a KendoGrid component like this:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid
          [data]="gridData"
          [hideHeader]="true"
          >
            <kendo-grid-column class="cell" field="key"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column class="cell" field="value"></kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .k-grid td.cell {
            text-align: center;
        }
    `],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
    public json = {
        "TestId": 2,
        "CurrentTestVersion": 1,
        "TestNumber": "2015-29059",
        "SharingData": 1.000000,
        "ThresholdValue": 0.0,
        "ExpireDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
        "UpdateDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00",
        "TestCurrency": "INR",
        "TestCode": "44300",
        "TestUCode": "UU",
        "IndexType": "TRE",
        "IndexUCode": "EUR",
        "IndexUMCode": "not",
    };

    public gridData: any = Object.keys(this.json).map((key) => {
        return {
            key: key,
            value: this.json[key]
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the result:
[image: Grid with json data]